# use solr4.10.2 delta import, but did not work

Tags: mysql, solr

```
<entity name="id" pk="id" query="select * from user;" 
                    deltaImportQuery="select * from user where id='${dataimporter.delta.id}';"
                    deltaQuey="select id from user where create_time > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}';">
            </entity>
```

solr 4.10.2 full import works well,but delta import did not work ,mysql create_time is a timestamp

the tomcat log:

```
2871263 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter  [   ] ?.Starting Delta Import
2871270 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SimplePropertiesWriter  [   ] ?.Read dataimport.properties
2871278 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher  [   ] ?.Opening Searcher@7dd0425a[collection1] realtime
2871282 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder  [   ] ?.Starting delta collection.
2871288 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder  [   ] ?.Running ModifiedRowKey() for Entity: id
2871293 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder  [   ] ?.Completed ModifiedRowKey for Entity: id rows obtained : 0
2871293 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder  [   ] ?.Completed DeletedRowKey for Entity: id rows obtained : 0
2871296 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder  [   ] ?.Completed parentDeltaQuery for Entity: id
2871297 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder  [   ] ?.Delta Import completed successfully
2871298 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder  [   ] ?.Import completed successfully
```

it sames no query the mysql

Comment: check the below links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660294/solr-delta-import-does-not-work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580331/solr-delta-import-not-working

Comment: i'm try those method ,but dit not work,upstairs is my running log